# Hints on proving $e$ like inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, inequality

Now, please excuse the whacky title, but I want to prove the following inequality which sure does look a lot like $e$.

Let $ m \in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed and $ n\in \mathbb{N}$

For $m>n$

$$(1+\frac{1}{m})^m\geq \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}  (\prod\limits_{x=1}^{k-1}(1-\frac{x}{m}))$$

Now I know that the limit of the left side and the limit of the infinite sum $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} $ is $e$ so I'm thinking there is a nicer way than using induction. However, since the only requirement is m being greater than n were are not just talking about limits here.

**Could you please provide some hints on how to approach this inequality?**

Comment: Binomial expansion of $(1 + y)^m$, with $y = \frac{1}{m}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to Daniel Fischer:

I expand and get:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{1}{m^{m}}\geq \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}  (\prod\limits_{x=1}^{k-1}(1-\frac{x}{m}))$$

As this does not seem a lot closer to the solution I divided by the sum ( is this valid? )

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{{n \choose k} \frac{1}{m^{m}}}{\frac{1}{k!}  (\prod\limits_{x=1}^{k-1}(1-\frac{x}{m}))}\geq 1$$

Now I could show that the denominator is always smaller than the other side by induction. **Is this useful, especially considering that we have two variables? Would I do induction over n, as m is fixed or how would it work?**

Comment: You should get $$(1 + 1/m)^m = \sum_{k = 0}^m \binom{m}{k} \frac{1}{m^k} = \sum_{k = 0}^m \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{r = 0}^{k-1} \frac{m - r}{m}.$$ From that, it's a short step to the goal.

Comment: It seems like I have a lot of work to do in terms of learning how to move the indexes and how to work with the sum and product signs. Especially the way you rewrote the binomial coefficient was not known to me. Thank you very much

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last step? I see $\sum\limits_{k=0}^m {m \choose k} \frac{1}{m^{k}} =  \sum\limits_{k=0}^m \prod\limits_{r=1}^{k} \frac{m+1-r}{r}  \frac{1}{m^k}$ but not how you go beyond that to the term you have gotten

Comment: Pull the denominators out of the product. That gives $\prod\limits_{r = 1}^k \frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{k!}$. We also have $k$ factors $\frac{1}{m}$, associate one of those with each $m+1-r$ to get $\left(\prod\limits_{r = 1}^k (m+1-r)\right)\frac{1}{m^k} = \prod\limits_{r = 1}^k \frac{m+1-r}{m}$. Rewrite the factors in that as $1 - \frac{r-1}{m}$. Shift the index, let $x = r-1$. Note the factor for $x=0$ is $1$ and can be dropped. Then you have $$\sum_{k = 0}^m \frac{1}{k!}\prod_{x = 1}^{k-1}\biggl(1-\frac{x}{m}\biggr).$$ Which is almost the right hand side. Only we sum to $m$ instead of to $n$.

Comment: I can not thank you enough for taking the time!